# How to connect JLabels with a line on JPanel with MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

I searched a lot on google on this subject, but just can't come out with right solution. I tried "painting" with `Graphics paintComponent` and everything seems fine, but lines just doesn't appear on my `JPanel`.
Part of my code with `JLabels` created:

```
frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("New family tree");
        ...
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[][][][][][][][]"));


    JButton newPersonButton = new JButton("New Person");
    panel.add(newPersonButton, "cell 0 5");

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tree", null, scrollPane, null);

    panel_1 = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(new MigLayout("",
            "[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]",
            "[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]"));

    final JLabel lblAddGreatgrandmother = new JLabel("Add Great-grandmother");
    panel_1.add(lblAddGreatgrandmother, "cell 3 4,growx");

    final JLabel lblAddGrandmother_1 = new JLabel("Add Grandmother");
    panel_1.add(lblAddGrandmother_1, "cell 2 5");
```

Should I use painting? Or put `JLabels` in array list and use `Point`? I'll appriciate any help.

EDIT: Runnable example - http://pastebin.com/NFug1QA1

Comment: *"Should I use painting? Or put JLabels in array list and use Point?"*  You might use both, neither or either..  I don't see that as an either/or question!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) though it would be better if you could simplify it to just 2 labels and a J2SE layout.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll do that as soon as possible.

Comment: http://java-sl.com/connector.html

Comment: Here you go - http://pastebin.com/NFug1QA1

I need all this panels because my whole project is based on them.

Comment: @StanislavL - thanks, one method worked for me, I can place lines now, just can't fix them on right position because I'm not using `null layout` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the java-sl.com/connector solution is that the connection itself becomes a component- ie needs layout, accepts events etc. I put together a solution for this years ago, which you can find in my [sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/). Specifically, see ConnectionPanel and Connection.

... Also, just in my experience, they kinds of connections are most useable when the layout manager is set to null and components are not restricted to being locked into position. But you will know what's best for your case.

Comment: I'm using `migLayout`, now I'm realizing that `null` would be much, much better for my project. Too bad I can't change that now... I can place lines now, just can't fix them on right position. Thank for your help. ;)